# jQuery droppable bind function on element drop?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, droppable

How can I bind a function on the `drop` event, but outside of the `droppable()` function?

```
$('#list').droppable({
    // ...      
    drop: function(e,ui) {
       // this works...
    },
});


// ..but I want to bind my function here
```

Is this possible?

Comment: well the problem is that I have not control over that droppable function, that's why I need to do this from outside...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. Bind to the "drop" event as you would any other event.

```
$( "#list" ).bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
  ...
});
```